# Write a function to return "true" or "false" if passed "1"/"0" or "true"/"false"

Tags: ruby

I need a simple function to return "true" or "false" the argument passed to it is:

`1` or `0`, or `true` or `false`

I currently had something like this, so the answer, if possible, should be concise as per below:

```
def boolean(value); return value ? ( value == 1 ? "true" : "false) : nil; end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Something to consider: Putting a method all on one line results in confusing code. If you have any logic at all, break it onto multiple lines. It'll read better, which will help when you're looking at the code at 4:00AM and you're slightly hung-over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
def boolean(x)
   %w{1 true}.include?(x).to_s
end
```

---

```
def boolean(x)
  (x == '1' || x == 'true').to_s
end
```

There's also the [wannabe bool](https://github.com/prodis/wannabe_bool) gem:

```
require 'wannabe_bool'

'1'.to_b # => true
'0'.to_b # => false

'true'.to_b  # => true
'false'.to_b # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look how Rails does this typecasting in its database connection adapter:

```
TRUE_VALUES = [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE', 'on', 'ON'].to_set

# convert something to a boolean
def value_to_boolean(value)
  if value.is_a?(String) && value.empty?
    nil
  else
    TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
  end
end
```

See: [docs for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.9/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column.html#method-c-value_to_boolean)

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work, comments are welcome though:

```
def b(k); return k ? ( (k == "1" || k == "true") ? "true" : "false" ) : nil; end

puts b("1")
puts b("0")

puts b("true")
puts b("false")
```

Result:

```
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: Why do you try to write it all in one line? Ternary operator is really cool, but not nested.

Comment: @nathanvda it is too nested.  As you can clearly see in his example.

Comment: No, don't do that. There's no speed advantage to writing it on one line, and it's certainly not macho to write code that makes it harder for others to read. Think "kinder and gentler".

Comment: Exactly, vgoff, that was my point. But maybe the OP had a special reason to write it like that. Like the Tin Man says: I prefer readability over coolness :) If the checking for `nil` was really important, it would go for a quick exit if the given value was nil.

Comment: My specific use case was to keep the function as close to a one liner as possible. This was to make the code change inline with what was already preset. I didn't want to refactor a whole bunch of other code to submit a simple patch.